# Underground Dirt and Gravel

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is the presence of dirt and gravel underground supposed to be a an indication of something being in the area (eg. minerals or ores) or is it just placed there when the world is generated just for the hell of it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dirt and Gravel are found underground, along with stone, water, lava, and occasionally obsidian. All of these are 'natural', with no significance. (You can also sometimes find sand)

Moss Stone indicates Dungeons, and if you find Wood/Rails, that's usually an indication you've wandered into an abandoned mine-- but gravel and dirt alone are inconsequential. They're just there for variety.

Comment: But many people have found that if u dig out the dirt or gravel u may just find some ores hidden behind them.

Comment: @Shangz - that's a form of memory bias; which is to say, they remember the times they dug beyond dirt/gravel and found ores more clearly than they remember the many more times they dug beyond dirt/gravel and found nothing.

Comment: @Raven Is it really memory bias if you actually do find ore more often when digging through dirt? (not more often in the sense that there's more ore there, but more often because digging through dirt/gravel is faster than digging through rock)

Comment: @Fambida - You'd still be associating a cause (finding dirt) with an unrelated effect (discovering ore) in exception to the actual reason (more blocks mined / minute)

Answer (score 0):

I found dirt while mining at y11, found it odd since I didn't think dirt was underground, so I looked it up. one of the comments said that there might be ores behind it, so I dug it out. I found iron, emeralds, and redstone galore! fs recommend digging it out.

Comment: That's just chance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirt vein just now and dug behind it in the hopes of finding tons of ores, i found coal. and i was about to stop wasting my time when i found a diamond, my first 1 in this world and so i destroyed all the dirt, i got no more diamonds but idrc cuz i got 14 gold also a bunch of copper and this wasnt very deep so ima say imo it probably does give ores. I think.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).